# Can P2P be done without port forwarding?

Tags: networking, p2p, irc, file-transfer, portforwarding

I was making a simple file transfer program through IRC and when I was reading up I saw that IRC when sharing a file creates a direct connection between the two users independent of the server (DCC, Direct Client Connect). After searching a while I have found this: [Direct Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Connect_%28file_sharing%29) and [Advanced Direct Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Direct_Connect).

None of these pages answer this question that I can't get out of my head: **Is P2P data transfer possible without any user doing a special port-forward?**
An intermediate server which helps set up the connection (as in the IRC examples) is allowed. The data transfer itself must be independent of the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - if you can get an external server to forward the connection request for you, there are so-called hole-punching techniques that can be used to set up a direct connection. [This technical paper](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/) has a more detailed explanation.

Note that these do not necessarily work on *all* NATs - but they do work on quite a lot of them.

Comment: +1 for hole-punching, exactly what I mean, didn't know what the terminology is.

Answer (score 1):

Practical JXTA II (available for reading on Scribd) has a chapter explaining techniques to perform NAT traversal. Hole punching is a subset of techniques to perform NAT traversal.