# Client-Server Unix Sockets and port forwarding

Tags: linux, sockets, client-server, portforwarding

we are building a chat application using Unix/Linux sockets. Currently I am having problem understanding when is port forwarding necessary. We would like to make a point-to-point type of a system where the chat server is only used to connect two clients together. After this the two clients talk directly to each other. My question is, if the two clients are talking to each other, than they technically have a small listener that waits for the incoming client connection (simply put they have a small server as well), do we need port forwarding in this case? Thanks in advance.

[When is port forwarding necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290412/when-is-port-forwarding-necessary?newreg=275b4d265dc8426f9f4559d2ea196247)

Answer (score 0):

It's not about who's the server or who's the client but about who starts the conversation.

If the chat clients start the connection you don't need to forward a port because the router knows where to send the packets.

If the server wants to start the connection (or the other chat client) they will send the packets to the router so the router needs to know where the client is, so you need to forward a port.

TL;DR You don't need port forwarding, just tell each client where the other client listens.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how the two chat clients discover each other, at some point one will have to initiate a direct connection with the other.

Let's call the two sides the `connecting` side and the `publishing` side (since the first side sets up the connection to an IP address published by the other side).

The `connecting` side has the easy job, because it knows the external IP address and port of the `publishing` side.  It can just send the SYN packet out to establish the connection, and your residential router will send it out to the internet.  The router will transparently NAT this connection, so inbound traffic will be correctly routed to the machine establishing the connection.

However ... what IP address should the `publishing` side expose?  If there are several computers sat behind a residential router, then these will all have internal IP addresses (e.g. 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2 etc).  The router has a "real" external IP address, but any traffic going there (which isn't NAT'd) would normally stop at the router as it doesn't know which internal IP address to go to.

One solution is to configure port forwarding on the router on a known port, for example 7876.  Any inbound packets destined for 7876 will be routed to a (possibly different) port on a configured internal address.

This is quite inflexible and inaccessible to many users, so another technique is hole-punching - see [Can P2P be done without port forwarding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692367/can-p2p-be-done-without-port-forwarding)

The issue with the 'listener' mentioned in the question, is it would need to bind to an internal IP address.  The only way the listener would receive inbound connections is if the upstream router knows to route traffic on a certain port to that address/port.